# What is meant by 'tying data to DOM' in JavaScript, and why is it bad?

Tags: javascript, dom

Almost all articles say that tying data to the DOM is bad. But what does that mean, exactly; and how can I avoid it?

Comment: @Dems 'Meany' means I was typing in a hurry and hit 'y' instead of 't' :)

Comment: @Nitin Is there a link to the article that you referred to?

Comment: @Rezigned You can check the introduction section in http://backbonejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Usually separating application logic, data and the display of data makes the application itself more clear and easy to maintain. Usually each part has their own separate problems (how to organize user data (model) is not related to what color/position username should be shown in on screen). How the username is transferred to the screen (controller) is also separate from the display (view).

I don't know which case you mean by tying data to the DOM, but one risk is that your model & view get mixed and it becomes difficult to separate display from data.

One way of doing this is MVC (model-view-controller) division and other similar separations like MVVM etc. Some more about MVC [here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvc-and-mvp-for-javascript-and-backbone-developers/).

Comment: I understand the MVC part but dont quite get what is meant by the phrase 'tying data to DOM'. Does it mean creating elements and giving them ids based on the content they are storing and then using these ids to retrieve the element from the DOM when they need to be updated?

Comment: I guess it could mean that (although it would be a really weird thing to do). Or it could mean using data-attributes to store a lot of data to DOM-elements - the safer/faster option might be to keep that data in a JS object.

Comment: Yes it would be extremely weird (not to mention unmanageable and stupid). The data attribute argument makes much more sense.

Comment: One possible interpretation could be that DOM is considered reserved for view. This way all things model would stay out of DOM. I don't know if that kind of purism is good or practical, but might fit the "keep data out of DOM" idea.